# EXIF datatypes interpretation

Tags: c, types, jpeg, exif, metadatatype

I am looking into the EXIF format to write a parser. The tags are present here. http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html#LightSource

1)Some of the fields have 'undef' as the datatype. How would you use such a field? What type do we assume it to be?

2) Some datatypes are like this int16u[2]!.  The exclamation means unsafe(when the cursor moves over it). But, what does that mean?

3) Another datatype is N. I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Why don't you use (or at least compare how these tags are handled by) [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) or [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: I can't make sense of the values for YCbCrSubSampling: 
0x0212 YCbCrSubSampling int16u[2]! IFD0 '1 1' = YCbCr4:4:4 (1 1) 
'1 2' = YCbCr4:4:0 (1 2) 
'1 4' = YCbCr4:4:1 (1 4) 
'2 1' = YCbCr4:2:2 (2 1)    '2 2' = YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2) 
'2 4' = YCbCr4:2:1 (2 4) 
'4 1' = YCbCr4:1:1 (4 1) 
'4 2' = YCbCr4:1:0 (4 2)

Answer (score 1):

I see that the mentioned document has been revised at 13-Oct-2012, which is after you have asked your question. So I suggest to check again - maybe it has less "holes" now.